# What is the distance to right margin in nested aligned and enumerate environments?

Tags: margins, alignment, parbox

I am using the `\aligned` environment within an `\enumerate` setup for formatting my assignment submissions. I have tried using the `\align*`, `\flalign*`, and `\alignat` environments but they didn't behave well in my experiments. I have created a new `environ` that defaults `\item` content to math mode (appropriate for my use case). However, when I need to enter longer bits of text, it overflows the right margin.

> `\text` overflowing the right margin in `aligned` environment:
>
> [image: Image of text overflowing the right margin]

To address this, I created a `\mathbox` command that is intended to create a `\parbox` extending exactly to the right margin from where it is placed. Unfortunately, the calculation seems to be off and the `\parbox` either overflows or doesn't reach the margin.

> `\parbox` not reaching the right margin:
>
> [image: Image of \parbox not reaching the right margin]

> `\parbox` not overflowing the right margin:
>
> [image: Image of \parbox overflowing the right margin]

These are the relevant parts of my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
% ...
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}

%%% packages - not sure which ones were necessary so I just included them all
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs,array,paralist,verbatim,subfig,sectsty, makecell,enumitem,titlesec,lmodern,slantsc,listings,setspace,amsmath, environ,showframe,nccmath,xifthen,adjustbox}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
% ...
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{11}{13.75}\sffamily\mdseries\scshape}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textbf{Question \arabic*.}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{(\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii})}
\setlist[enumerate]{align=left, listparindent=2em, parsep=0pt}
% ...
\newenvironment{answergroup}{\begin{enumerate}[parsep=10pt]\begingroup\everymath{\displaystyle}
\setstretch {1.3}}{\endgroup\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{answerbody}{\begingroup\everymath{\displaystyle}
\setstretch {1.3}}{\endgroup}
\newcommand{\nextline}{\end{aligned}\\\begin{aligned}[t]&\\&}
\NewEnviron{aligneditem}[1][]{
    \begingroup
    %\allowdisplaybreaks - does nothing in aligned mode
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
    {\item}
    {\item[#1]}
    $\begin{aligned}[t]
    &\BODY
    \end{aligned}$
    \endgroup
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% THIS ↓ \dimexpr needs to be fixed somehow %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\mathbox}[1]{\boxed{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\listparindent-\itemindent}{#1}}}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\section{Basic Distributions}
\subsection{Binomial Distributions}
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{3}
\begin{answerbody}
\begin{aligneditem}
\mathbox{
The binomial distribution arises when a random variable is determined to be the number of successes in a series of $n$ independent random trials. In these trials the probability of success is $p$ for each trial, and there are only two possible outcomes: success or failure.
}
\end{aligneditem}
\end{answerbody}
\begin{answerbody}
\begin{aligneditem}
\end{aligneditem}
\end{answerbody}
\begin{answergroup}
\begin{aligneditem}[\unskip]
\mu \geq \frac{5 * 0 + 30 * 1 + 56 * 2 + 15 * 3 + 10 * 4 + 7 * 5}{123} = \frac{262}{123} \\&
\implies \text{Possibly }X \sim \text{Po}(\lambda)\text{ where }\lambda \geq \frac{262}{123}\\&
\mathbox{It appears that sampled stroke patients make at least 2.13 errors on average on this psychometric test.}\\&
\displaystyle\sigma^{2} \geq \sum_{x}{\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{N}} \\&
= \frac{1}{123}\left(\begin{multlined}5\left(0 - \frac{262}{123}\right)^{2} + 30\left(1 - \frac{262}{123}\right)^{2} + 56\left(2 - \frac{262}{123}\right)^{2}\\
+ 15\left(3 - \frac{262}{123}\right)^{2} + 10\left(4 - \frac{262}{123}\right)^{2} + 10\left(5 - \frac{262}{123}\right)^{2}\end{multlined}\right)\\&
% ...
\end{aligneditem}
\end{answergroup}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

How should I properly calculate the remaining space to the right margin for `\parbox`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: your `\mathbox` is a framed text (not math) `\parbox` so I don't understand the name but something like `\newcommand{\mathbox}[1]{\fbox{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\labelwidth-\labelsep-\listparindent-\itemindent-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{#1}}}%`

Comment: I agree that the name is somewhat misleading, but it can be changed. Your suggestion seem to leave the box on the left of the margin, but leaves a gap between the right side of the box and the margin. Is there a way that makes this gap as small as possible?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing the width of the `\parbox` to `\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftmargin-\listparindent+\parskip-\labelsep-\listparindent`. I'm not quite sure why this works, but it gets reasonably close to the margin without overflowing, for my use cases. The code after modification is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
% ...
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}

%%% packages - not sure which ones were necessary so I just included them all
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs,array,paralist,verbatim,subfig,sectsty, makecell,enumitem,titlesec,lmodern,slantsc,listings,setspace,amsmath, environ,showframe,nccmath,xifthen}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
% ...
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{11}{13.75}\sffamily\mdseries\scshape}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textbf{Question \arabic*.}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{(\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii})}
\setlist[enumerate]{align=left, listparindent=2em, parsep=0pt}
% ...
\newenvironment{answergroup}{\begin{enumerate}[parsep=10pt]\begingroup\everymath{\displaystyle}
\setstretch {1.3}}{\endgroup\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{answerbody}{\begingroup\everymath{\displaystyle}
\setstretch {1.3}}{\endgroup}
\newcommand{\nextline}{\end{aligned}\\\begin{aligned}[t]&\\&}
\newcommand{\textbox}[1]{\boxed{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftmargin-\listparindent+\parskip-\labelsep-\listparindent}{#1}}}
\NewEnviron{aligneditem}[1][]{
    \begingroup
    %\allowdisplaybreaks - does nothing in aligned mode
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
    {\item}
    {\item[#1]}
    $\begin{aligned}[t]
    &\BODY
    \end{aligned}$
    \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
\section{Basic Distributions}
\subsection{Binomial Distributions}
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{3}
\begin{answerbody}
\begin{aligneditem}
\textbox{
The binomial distribution arises when a random variable is determined to be the number of successes in a series of $n$ independent random trials. In these trials the probability of success is $p$ for each trial, and there are only two possible outcomes: success or failure.
}
\end{aligneditem}
\end{answerbody}
\begin{answerbody}
\begin{aligneditem}
\end{aligneditem}
\end{answerbody}
\begin{answergroup}
\begin{aligneditem}[\unskip]
\mu \geq \frac{5 * 0 + 30 * 1 + 56 * 2 + 15 * 3 + 10 * 4 + 7 * 5}{123} = \frac{262}{123} \\&
\implies \text{Possibly }X \sim \text{Po}(\lambda)\text{ where }\lambda \geq \frac{262}{123}\\&
\textbox{It appears that sampled stroke patients make at least 2.13 errors on average on this psychometric test.}\\&
\displaystyle\sigma^{2} \geq \sum_{x}{\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{N}} \\&
= \frac{1}{123}\left(\begin{multlined}5\left(0 - \frac{262}{123}\right)^{2} + 30\left(1 - \frac{262}{123}\right)^{2} + 56\left(2 - \frac{262}{123}\right)^{2}\\
+ 15\left(3 - \frac{262}{123}\right)^{2} + 10\left(4 - \frac{262}{123}\right)^{2} + 10\left(5 - \frac{262}{123}\right)^{2}\end{multlined}\right)\\&
% ...
\end{aligneditem}
\end{answergroup}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

It produces this output:
[image: Final output with proper alignment]